# Needing Some Visa advice

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

I’m hoping someone can help out here ! My girlfriend of almost 3 years is a US citizen and coming to the UK for 5 months to see me but she don’t know that while she is here I’m going to propose to her. Is it possible to then apply for a fiancé Visa while she is in the UK?

Comment: Fiance visa for what? Are you planning to get married while she is with you?

Comment: My thoughts on this are, your girlfriend on this trip doesn't have an intention of getting married at that trip(based on the info in the question) and hence you shouldn't preemptively apply for a fiancee visa.

She could also say no, you know.

Comment: People with leave to enter for 6 months or less can't switch to a family visa while in the UK anyway. See the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa). If she says yes, and wants to move to the UK with you, then you can ask follow-up questions on our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: @Sami Has your girlfriend visited the UK for that length of time before? Although as a US citizen she can enter visa-free for up to 6 months, official advice is to bring the same documents she’d use to apply for a visa https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents to show at Immigration, if asked.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that sounds like an answer.